# When is an opencart session token accepted as valid?

Tags: opencart, token

And this includes the sub-question: How is an opencart token generated?

I ask this because I have made an installation of opencart that was copied (DB's and everything) and only the respective `config.php` and `admin/config.php` were modified (caches were all deleted) and this was done like 30 times.

All is fine and all stores work. Their respective store owners have different passwords and are able to log in and manipulate their stores.
The thing is... All stores are accessible as sub folders of my domain.

```
domain.com/store1

domain.com/store2

etc.
```

Here's the kicker: Logging into one store with the owner's password (say `domain.com/store1/admin`) works ok and generates a token for the session.
The problem is... that the token is now accepted in all stores (whose owner are different people with different passwords)!

Simply by changing the url from:

```
domain.com/store1/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=3b029982197b80009b608328508aade2
```

to

```
domain.com/store2/admin/index.php?route=common/home&token=3b029982197b80009b608328508aade2
```

works and now Store owner 1 has access to Store owner 2's admin panel without ever knowing or entering his password.

Quite critical!

How do I make it so that this is not possible. Help me understand these opencart tokens please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could achieve what you want. You could either

- Save the store's URI in a session variable alongside the token that can be validated against
- Save the token in the user table and validate against that

The actual validation of the token is done in `/admin/controller/common/home.php` in the method `login()`